# Don't want column names to appear

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to upload data from asp.net WebAPI to a table in AngularJS. It's working fine. But if any error occurs, then column names is being displayed (like name, id, salary) but no data. I want that column names as well not to be displayed if the error occurs.

Comment: Can you please provide us a code?

Comment: It's the normal code that we use to display data from webAPI to html page using angular JS. How can we make sure the columns are not displayed if the data is not loading.

Comment: Maybe you need to apply `ng-show` to your table header and bind it to model property containing data. So it will show if there is any data and it will hide if there is no data at all.

Comment: please accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: That you put your json data put in your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to apply `ng-show` to your table header and bind it to model property containing data. So it will show if there is any data and it will hide if there is no data at all.